# Is there an alternative to R squared to compare goodness of fits of different datasets? Slope makes them incomparable

Tags: least-squares, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I'm fitting the degradation of a signal. Some instruments degrade faster than others, so the slope varies a bit. This makes it difficult to compare how good the fits are relative to eachother.

See example below. Two scatter plots with a comparable spread of data (shared x and y axes). Eye-balling the data I expect the left one will have a slightly worse fit, but I guess I did not expect R-squared to be 1.5 orders of magnitude different!

[image: Similar plots, wildly different R-squared.]

I'm starting to understanding that R-squared is also measure of X-Y correlation. So I guess for this case, where flat signals are possible, it's not very useful... or I've got the wrong approach altogether.

Would there be an alternative to compare the goodness of these fits? Something relative is ok. I'm thinking about if I could somehow set a boundary/range... but I'm just not familiar enough with the subject and I'd probably be just be badly reinventing the wheel :)

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider a measure of accuracy that measures the distance between the line and the data.  There are a variety of these types of measures, maybe including Mean Absolute Error, Mean Square Error, or Root Mean Square Error.

The following is an example in R.  The amount of vertical error for `model` and `model2`  are the same, but `model` has zero slope and zero r-squared, while `model2` has an obvious slope and a high r-squared. You can compare the `MAE`, `MSE`, or `RMSE` statistics. (Caveat: I am the author of the `accuracy` function.)

```
if(!require(rcompanion)){install.packages("rcompanion")}
library(rcompanion)

X = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Y = c(5,6,4,5,5,5,5,4,6,5)

model = lm(Y ~ X)

plot(Y ~ X)

accuracy(list(model), plotit=F)

    ### Min.max.accuracy MAE   MAPE MSE  RMSE NRMSE.mean NRMSE.median NRMSE.mean.accuracy NRMSE.median.accuracy Efron.r.squared CV.prcnt
    ###            0.927 0.4 0.0833 0.4 0.632      0.126        0.126               0.874                 0.874               0     12.6           

X = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
Z = X + c(5,6,4,5,5,5,5,4,6,5)

model2 = lm(Z ~ X)

plot(Z ~ X)

accuracy(list(model2), plotit=F)

   ### Min.max.accuracy MAE   MAPE MSE  RMSE NRMSE.mean NRMSE.median NRMSE.mean.accuracy NRMSE.median.accuracy Efron.r.squared CV.prcnt
   ###            0.961 0.4 0.0418 0.4 0.632     0.0602       0.0602                0.94                  0.94           0.954     6.02
```

Comment: Thank you Sal. Very nice all together. Would you say RMSE is probably the best one then for this case with OLS fitting? Or are they pretty equivalent, and down to preference (like metric vs. imperial)?

There wouldn't happen to be anything as straight forward in a Python library as your accuracy function by any chance? 

I've been using the sklearn library, not for ML, just for its regression metrics. (It's a a bit finicky about the shapes of the input data, but I'm wrapping another class around it for my own needs, so it's all learning.)

Comment: I don't know if I have a specific recommendation. RMSE is common, and nice because it's on the same scale as the Y variable.  But this also means it doesn't take into account the relative value of the differences relative to the absolute value of, say, mean of Y.  Also, RMSE, because it squares the differences, is more sensitive to outlying values. ... I'll also note to be careful with MAE and similar sounding names. There's Mean absolute error, Mean absolute deviation, and Mean absolute difference, and I think they are sometimes conflated in literature.

Comment: Any of them are pretty easy to calculate if you can get 1) the difference between the predicted values and the actual values, and 2) the actual values.  I don't know if there's an implementation in Python, but I imagine there would be.